# Is there a way to restrict functions in a C# class to only use a specific signature?

Tags: c#, compile-time

I am writing a class that should ideally have multiple methods of the same signature. Is there a way to force the class to check its methods if all of them follow the same signature?

It would be ideal if the check could be done at compile-time/during build

If you assume the signature to be `int <methodName>(string, int, char)`

```
public class Conditions {
        // no error
        int MethodA(string a, int b, char c)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // no error
        int MethodB(string a, int b, char c)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        // should throw error because return type does not match signature
        string MethodC(string a, int b, char c)
        {
            return "Should throw an error for this function";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want it to throw, why not pick it up at compile time, in such case just use a contract like an interface.

Comment: Why do you want that? It's a very unusual requests that suggests the actual problem is something different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've needed to do that before...

Comment: @MichaelRandall I doubt an `interface` would help here - it seems that adding an arbitrary `int Foo(string a, int b, char c)` would be fine, but `Foo` wouldn't exist in any interface - it is the signature that seems to matter, presumably due to something reflection-esque

Comment: @MarcGravell for what reason? I can understand implementing Commands or something similar, that can be implemented using interfaces. The compiler can't force all methods to have the same signature though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will be using this class as a way for my users to add their custom C# code into and I would like the method signatures to be standardized so I could call their code easier.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my case - and I suspect OP's - the methods are detected and activated via some form of reflection; I just want to ensure that they stand a chance of working (also: I have unit tests to dynamically test them as far as is reasonable)

Comment: As Panagiotis Kanavos is stating, there is no way of forcing the Compiler to restrict a Class to have the same signatures, this requires manual behavior. What is your scenario, maybe there is a "better/other" way of achieving this?

Comment: @MarcGravell or they can be passed through `Func<>` delegates, forcing the compiler to complain if they don't have the correct signature. F# *function* pipelines and composition work that way

Comment: @sahil.kr - can you not force the users to provide a registration function that registers their code (avoids you having to reflect) that's defined to return `IEnumerable<(string,Func<string,int,char,int>)>`?

Comment: I would never like to contradict @MarcGravell, however "*I would like the method signatures to be standardized so I could call their code easier*" sounds like a job for an interface

Comment: @MichaelRandall interfaces enforce full signatures; in this example, I don't think OP means the full signature - just the args and return value, while name is irrelevant; also - it looks like arbitrary additional methods would be part of the same family - interfaces don't work that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of cheating, but if you require the developer to *register* their methods, you can force a compile time error by requiring the method to match a delegate.

This is essentially how event handlers and callbacks work.

```
namespace Framework
{
    public delegate int MyApiSignature(int a, string b, char c);

    public class Core
    {
        static public void RegisterMethod(MyApiSignature method) 
        {
            //Doesn't even have to actually do anything
        }
    }
}


namespace Custom
{
    using Framework;

    class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Core.RegisterMethod(MethodA);  //Works
            Core.RegisterMethod(MethodB);  //Compile-time error
        }

        public int MethodA(int a, string b, char c)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int MethodB(int a, string b, byte c)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Conditions_MethodsHaveCorrectSignature()
    {
        var whitelist = new List<string> { "Finalize", "MemberwiseClone" };
        var t = typeof(Conditions);
        var m = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var item in m.Where(x => !whitelist.Contains(x.Name)))
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(int), item.ReturnType);

            CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<Type> { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(char) },
                item.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToList());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. You could write an analyzer for it using Roslyn, or you could write a unit test that checks the signatures via reflection.

Comment: Or a quick & dirty way - assign all the methods to a `Func<string,int,char,string>`. That will cause the compiler to complain. Very dirty though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not terrible, though - especially if you *are* activating them via reflection... a `Dictionary<string, Func<string,int,char,string>>` becomes very enticing

Comment: F#'s function composition essentially works by chaining `Func<>`s so maybe it isn't such a dirty solution